Proving the Convergence of a Series by Bounding the Difference Between Consecutive Terms
The question

Given the sequence $$a_n = n^p$$ for $p > 1$, and the increasing, bijective sequence $e_n \geq 1$ that satisfies the inequality $e_n < a_n$ for all $n \geq n_p$, and for every $p > 1$, is the following true? $$\sum_{n=n_p}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{e_n}} = +\infty$$

Introduction
While studying the convergence of some series, I defined a class of sets, denoted by the letter $E$, of real numbers that are greater or equal to 1, and which elements can be identified by an increasing and bijective sequence, named $e_n$ (this is, $E=\{e_1, e_2, ...\}$).
Next I was interested in analyzing the conditions under which the series of the reciprocals of the elements of $E$ converges or diverges.
With this purpose in mind, I defined the following:
Important definitions

The general E sets, now formally, a subset of the real numbers that satisfies both of these:


Any $x \in E$ is greater or equal to 1.

There exists an increasing and bijective sequence $e_n$ so that every $x \in E$ corresponds to one unique term of this sequence. In a more simple paraphrase, the set $E$ has to be contain every term of the sequence $e_n$, $$E = \{e_1, e_2, e_3, ...\}$$ and it will be said that $E$ is identified by $e_n$.



The generalized polynomials, functions of the form $$P(x)=C_1x^k+C_2x^{k-1}+...$$ where k (which is called the degree of the polynomial) and $C_1$ (the main coefficient) are any real number different from $0$, and $C_2, C_3, ... \in \mathbb{R}$. Using this, I will refer as 'polynomial in terms of the sequence $a_n$' to any expression of the form $P(a_n)$ where $P$ is a generalized polynomial. I will use these generalized polynomials to build lower and upper bounds for the difference between consecutive terms of sequences.

The $p$-sequences, sequences of the form $$a_n=n^p, p>1$$ For these, it is well known that the series of their reciprocals, $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{a_n}}$$ is convergent, as $p>1$.


Analysis of the problem
Based on the definitions above, I wanted to prove the following statement:
Given a general $E$ set that can be identified by the sequence $e_n$, then the series of the reciprocals of the elements $E$ converges if and only if there exists some $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ and a generalized polynomial $P$ in terms of $e_n$ with degree $k \in (0, 1)$ and positive main coefficient so that $$e_{n+1}-e_n\geq P(e_n) \quad \forall n \geq n_0$$
The first step is to prove that, if such $n_0$ and $P$ exist, then the series of the reciprocals of the elements of $E$ is convergent. For this, I directly assumed the hypotesis and found another generalized polynomial $T$ of degree $0 < \frac{p-1}{p} < k$ that is a lower bound for the difference $e_{n+1}-e_n$, by evaluating the difference between two consecutive terms of a $p$-sequence (the same $p$ of the degree of the polynomial), and expanding it accordingly to the Generalized Binomial Theorem. Then proved, using that the difference of consecutive terms of $e_n$ is greater than the difference of consecutive terms of a $p$-sequence for all $n \geq n_0$, and that there must exists some $n_1$ so that the sequence $e_n$ is greater than the $p$-sequence, that the series of reciprocals of $e_n$ must converge from $n_1$ to infinity, by applying the comparison test.
The last proved the first half of the statement. Next, I wanted to prove the other part, that if there does not exist such a generalized polynomial with degree $k > 0$ and main coefficient greater than $0$ that can lower bound the difference between two consecutive terms of $e_n$ for all $n \geq n_0$, then the series of the reciprocals of the elements of $E$ must diverge.
For this, I first proved that, if such polinomyal does not exist, then the difference of two consecutive terms of $e_n$ is a lower bound for the difference of consecutive terms of a sequence $p$-sequence, that I will call $$a_n=n^p,p>1$$ from now on. In order to prove this, I assumed that there must exist some subsequence $e_{\phi(n)}$ of $e_n$ that not only is not lower-bounded by a generalized polynomial. Furthermore, it satisfies the inequality $$P(e_{\phi(n)}) \geq e_{\phi(n+1)}-e_{\phi(n)}$$ be true for some generalized polynomial $P$ of degree $k > 0$. However, for the sake of simplicity and clarity, we will now consider $e_n$ to be the actual subsequence in question. This choice is valid because, if there exists at least one subsequence of $e_n$ for which the series of its reciprocals diverges, then the entire sequence will do the same.
After this, I found another generalized polynomial $T$ of degree $1 > \frac{p-1}{p} > k$ using the same strategy as before. Also, I assumed the existence of some $n_1$ so that $e_n < a_n$ for all $n \geq n_1$.
All of these assumptions led to this inequality $$\sum_{n=n_p}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{e_n}} \geq \sum_{n=n_p}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{a_n}}$$ As this holds for every $p>1$, I stated that it must still hold true when the limit as $p$ tends to 1 is taken, which is related to the main question. Based on this this, I used Cauchy's integral test, using the function $$f(x)=\frac{1}{x^p}, p>1, x\geq n_p$$ to show that the $p$-series converge accordingly to this expression $$-\frac{{n_p}^{1-p}}{1-p}$$ After this, evaluated the limit $$\lim_{p\to1^+}{-\frac{{n_p}^{1-p}}{1-p}}$$ and claimed that it diverges, causing the series $$\sum_{n=n_1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{e_n}}$$ to diverge too.
The question after the analysis
In the end, the actual question is if any of the assumptions I made was wrong. In particular, I believe the most controversial is to assume that the inequality $$\sum_{n=n_p}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{e_n}} \geq \sum_{n=n_p}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{a_n}}$$ holds even when taking the limit as $p$ tends to 1 from the positive side, and I would greatly appeciate any suggestion or explanation about whether it remains rigorous or if there is an error in my reasoning.
Additionally, this is my first time asking a question in a forum. Therefore I would be grateful for any advise that could help me improve in asking questions in a proper manner.

"Therefore I would be grateful for any advise that could help me improve in asking questions in a proper manner." - here is that advice: Talk to us yourself, not through an AI.
